# Regex to grab string until a hyphen

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I think I'm having an issue since I'm using two key regex values in this expression.

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-schedule$ /schedule.php?sport=$3&school=$1&year=$2&schedule=true [NC,L]
```

I this to be caught when someone types

> **domain.com/michigan-1999-football-schedule**

.  It currently doesn't recognize this string with this htaccess line, and I'm 99% it has to do with the regex part.  I think it's because the [^-] part of the line.  I am hoping this grabs the data until a hyphen, but I think there's an issue since both are key characters in regex.

Comment: `(foot|basket)(ball)` can just be written as `(foot|basket)ball`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me as-is.  Do you have other rules that you are using?

Make sure that you have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Long story short, another developer on the project moved everything from .htaccess to apache, but I'm sure others with the same question will need to consider this option, so I'll +1 it and mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use + instead of *, in the case some fields would be empty:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-((foot|basket)(ball))-schedule$ /schedule.php?sport=$3&school=$1&year=$2&schedule=true [NC,L]
```